# I can't click on submit input [Selenium Python]

Tags: python, selenium

I want introduce some text on an textarea field and click in the submit input.

I have the following inputs on html:

```
<textarea id="post-content" name="content" rows="2" cols="50"></textarea>
<input class="share" type="submit" value="Share status!">
```

And my python script is the next:

```
driver.get(url)
field = driver.find_element_by_name("content")
field.send_keys("foo")
field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='submit']")
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To identify the `submit input` you can use the following line of code:

```
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='share'][@value='Share status!']")
```

Comment: But I can't find it only by the @type?